# Get multiple rows value(with input text) from html table and save into DB

Tags: php

i had research for this problem but I cant find a solution to fix it. I had a table which retrieve the list of result from Google Book API and display it on a HTML table together with the input textbox. This allow user to multiple select the record and enter the required field so that it can be save into database. Now i stuck on how to retrieve the checked rows value in order to save in database. Can anyone help on this problem?

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
            <div class="box-body">
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Author</th>
                  <th>Publisher</th>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th>ISBN</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php 
                    $page = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%22%22&printType=books&maxResults=40&key=AIzaSyDIY54a21pPyYnXfx8CMJGrf8fdG_Cp-fQ");

                    $data = json_decode($page, true);

                    foreach ($data['items'] as $book) {
                        $Title = $book["volumeInfo"]["title"];
                        $Authors = @implode(",", $book["volumeInfo"]["authors"]);

                        echo "
                        <tr>
                          <td>".'<input type="checkbox" value ="" name="toadd[]" >'."</td>
                          <td>".$Title."</td>
                          <td>".$Authors."</td>
                          <td>".'<input type="text" id="txtPublisher" name="txtPublisher" placeholder="Publisher" >'."</td>
                          <td>".'<input type="text" id="txtCategory" name="txtCategory" placeholder="Category" >'."</td>
                          <td>".'<input type="text" id="txtISBN" name="txtISBN" placeholder="ISBN" >'."</td>
                          <td>".'<input type="text" id="txtQuantity" name="txtQuantity" placeholder="Quantity" >'."</td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                    } 
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" name="add" id="add"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My exepected is the selected rows value can be retrieve and save into database.This is the image of the HTML table for reference[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mxMA.png)

Comment: change `name` attributes as array. for example `name="txtPublisher"` needs to be `name="txtPublisher[]"`, so that over-write issue of your form submission will rectified and you will get an array of records on which you have to do stuff accordingly.

Comment: i will try this later on. Just for double confirm, is there anything i miss? Because I still new to PHP and not sure i missing anything.

Comment: Unable to say, code is long an i  don't have enough time to check and tell all modification/changes needs to be done